# Compare two linear regressions each modeling a different correlation

Tags: r, anova

I'm uncertain how to establish the difference, if any, of **two linear models each representing a different correlation**. Consider, for example, this toy data, where `z` is the grouping variable:

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = c(1:10, 1:10),
  y = c(1,2,3,4,5,2,3,4,6,8,
        1,2,1,3,1,4,2,3,1,5),
  z = c(rep("A",10), rep("B",10))
)
```

The two models in questions are:

```
lm1 <- lm(df$y[df$z=="A"] ~ df$x[df$z=="A"])
lm2 <- lm(df$y[df$z=="B"] ~ df$x[df$z=="B"])
```

I seem to know that `anova` can be used to determine whether **two models representing the same data** are different:

```
anova(lm1, lm2)
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: df$y[df$z == "A"]
                  Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)   
df$x[df$z == "A"]  1 24.546 24.5455  13.043 0.006866 **
Residuals          8 15.055  1.8818                    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
Warning message:
In anova.lmlist(object, ...) :
  models with response ‘"df$y[df$z == \"B\"]"’ removed because response differs from model 1
```

But can `anova` be used to see if two correlations of essentially **different data** are significantly different? Are there alternative and better ways?

Comment: for anova the response should be the same. In your case, response is not same.

Comment: Ah okay, this confirms my doubts. Any suggestions as to what alternative test can be used?

Comment: Which two models are you comparing? You can compare models if they have same response with same number of observations. I do not know any study comparing models with different responses. Why would you want to compare those models in the first place?

Comment: The two models in the above example can simply be written as one model ie: `lm(y~x*z, df)` now check the coefficients and compare with `m1` and `m2`. You will note that they are the same. Meaning you have one model. Just different slopes and intercepts

Comment: @Onyambu You only need to do `anova(lm(y~x, df), lm(y~x*z, df))`. `lm1` and `lm2` are not useful for the comparison.

Comment: I think your question is off-topic here and has been answered at stats.stackexchange: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/231059/11849

Comment: In stats.stackexchange.com/q/231059/11849 the two data sets are the same; the difference between the models is that the first does not include the grouping variable whereas the second does. In my case the two data sets can be considered completely different: in the actual data, one models the cognitive effort of a certain type of RECIPIENT in speaking turns, the other models the cognitive effort of another type of RECIPIENT in these speaking turns. I want to find out whether the **increase** in cognitive effort in RECIPIENT "A" is greater than the increase in cognitive effort in RECIPIENT "B".

Comment: "In my case the two data sets can be considered completely different" Then you have your answer and no statistics are necessary. Is your goal perhaps comparing (predictive) model performance? Then you need to derive performance measures (perhaps based on cross-validation).

Comment: 'I want to find out whether the increase in cognitive effort in RECIPIENT "A" is greater than the increase in cognitive effort in RECIPIENT "B".' Fit `lm(y~x*z, df)` and look at the model coefficients.

Comment: In `Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)   0.8000     0.9125   0.877  0.39359   
x             0.5455     0.1471   3.709  0.00191 **
zB            0.2000     1.2904   0.155  0.87877   
x:zB         -0.3091     0.2080  -1.486  0.15665   
---
F-statistic: 7.549 on 3 and 16 DF,  p-value: 0.002289` `x             0.5455`is the coeff for "A" and `zB            0.2000`is the coeff for "B"  and the p-value is for the difference in slope?

Comment: The difference in slope is the `x : zB` coefficient.

Comment: Thanks a lot. And the p-value is for that difference, correct?

Comment: Yes, of course. (I'm assuming you don't change the default contrasts).